# How do you enable CRS rules in mod_security in Debian 9?

Tags: debian

`/usr/share/modsecurity-crs/` seems to have changed in Debian 9 (Stretch), and I assume this is because Debian 9 uses the latest version of mod_security? Anyways..

**How do I enable CRS rules in Debian 9?**

I tried to create a symlink like you used to in Debian 8 (Jessie) from:
`/usr/share/modsecurity-crs/rules`to `/etc/modsecurity` but with no luck.

Comment: I am keeping a couple of servers in Debian Jessie until I understand what is going on with mod security

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that all you have to do in order to setup mod_security in Debian 9 is to install the package and you're done. The rules are loaded by default.

`sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-security2`

The rules are now located in `/usr/share/modsecurity-crs/rules` and they are loaded by `/usr/share/modsecurity-crs/owasp-crs.load` which is included by security2.conf located at `/etc/apache2/mods-available/security2.conf`

Comment: could you elaborate? any possible links?

Comment: The rules in `/usr/share/modsecurity-crs/rules` are loaded by default from owasp-crs.load in `/usr/share/modsecurity-crs`. No link, found it out by myself

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I've updated the answer.